# C# TcpClient Won't Register Disconnect

Tags: c#

My server has a 'stop' button that should disconnect the client. The issue I'm having, is the client doesn't register that it's disconnected - or maybe it isn't disconnecting altogether. When I hit the red 'X' on my server window, the client will write in the console that it's disconnected, and try to reconnect. So, why doesn't my stop button have the same effect that closing the window does?

Hopefully these snippets will give you a better understanding of the problem I'm having:

Right here is the client. As you can see, it waits for commands from the server. If the 'try' fails(the server window is closed' it knows its disconnected, and says 'client disconnected' and attempts to reconnect.

```
 public static void waitForCommands()
    {
        while (client.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                readBuffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
                int data = stream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                string plainText = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, data);
                if (plainText.Contains("mbox"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(plainText.Split('<','>')[1]);
                }

                else if (plainText.Contains("process"))
                {
                    Process.Start(plainText.Split('<', '>')[1]);
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Client disconnected");
                new Thread(attemptConnection).Start();
            }

        }
    }
```

Right here is the code to my 'stop' button. It should have the same effect as closing the window(minus the part where the application closes), but it doesn't. When I click it, it causes the client to hang. It doesn't even attempt to reconnect.

```
private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            f.labelControl1.Text = "Disconnected";
            client.Client.Disconnect(true);
            server.Stop();
        }

        catch
        {

        }

    }
```

I've tried many other lines of code besides 'client.Client.Disconnect(true);' client.Close(); , client.Client.Close();, all had the same result

Comment: It's not throwing any errors at all

Comment: close your stream first before closing your client. lets see if that works since closing the client doesn't mean the stream will close.

Comment: I switched client.Client.Disconnect(true); with client.GetStream().Close();
and client.Client.Close(); Didn't seem to change anything

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts, you can just remove the accept mark on the answer and click the delete link under your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a socket disconnects, the `stream.Read()` on the other side will return 0 - only when the server stops abrubtly, your client will at some point catch an exception.

So just add a check if `data == 0` to handle a graceful disconnect. Close the stream on the client side to 'complete the circle'.

BTW you may want to distinguish `catch (SocketException)` from other exceptions instead of assuming "if something goes wrong, the server must have stopped".

Comment: I have a small question if you wouldn't mind answering(I couldn't find the answer on Google) What's the difference between client and client.Client?

Comment: The `TcpClient.Client` property gets the `Socket` it uses to communicate with. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.client(v=vs.110).aspx